# Calculation of area union of 3 overlapping circles

Tags: trigonometry

Please help calculate the total un-overlapped area of union inside a boundary consisting of perimeters of 3 different circles as shown. The two larger circles are 4.25 mm in diameter and the center circle is 3.28 mm.
All the circles are centered on x-axis, the distance between the 2 largest circle centers is 1.34 mm. The middle smaller circle is centered along y-axis.

[image: circles image]

Comment: the distance between the large circles seems to be a bit off...do you speak of distance between center-center?

Comment: The area of a perimeter is zero.

Comment: But now, looking at the title, I don't understand any more, what are you interested in : about area or perimeter ? What do you call "the area of the perimeter" ?

Comment: If it is an area that you want to estimate, say with 3 significant digits, use a [Monte Carlo simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).

Comment: This question isn't very clear. What do you mean by centered along a middle line?

Comment: @Aaron I simplified problem statement hopefully.If it is not exactly not what you wanted, please feel free to revert to your previous text.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by finding the combined area of the two larger circles. The area of one of the larger circles, which I will call $A_O$, is:

$$
\begin{align*}
A_O &= \frac14\pi d^2\\
&= \frac14\pi(4.25)^2\\
&\approx14.186
\end{align*}
$$

Thus the area of both circles, ignoring their intersection for a moment, is $2A_O$. To find the area between them, we can use [the formula for the area of a symmetric lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(geometry)),

$$A_\text{lens} = R^2(\theta-\sin\theta), \tag{*}\label{*}$$

where $R$ is the radius of the circles forming the lens, and $\theta$ the central angle in radians. We know $R = 4.25$, but we need to find $\theta$. To do so, draw in a few lines on the diagram:

[image]

(Note that I left out the smaller circle for simplicity's sake.) In the diagram, $\theta = m\angle AOB = 2\alpha$, and $R = OA = OC = OB$. We can find $\theta$ through $\triangle AOD$. The length of line segment $OD$ is equal to $OC-CD$, or the radius minus half the distance between the two circles. We also know the length of line segment $OA$, since it is the radius, so we can write:

$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \arccos\left(\frac{OD}{OA}\right)\\
&= \arccos\left( \frac{2.125-\frac12(1.34)}{2.125} \right)\\
&\approx .816596 \ \text{radians}
\end{align*}
$$

Since $\theta = 2\alpha$, $\theta=1.63319$. We can now use $\eqref{*}$:

$$
\begin{align*}
A_\text{lens} &= R^2(\theta-\sin\theta) \\
&= (2.125)^2(1.63319-\sin1.63319)\\
&\approx 2.868
\end{align*}
$$

Thus, the area between the two larger circles, $A_L$, is:

$$
\begin{align*}
A_L &= 2A_O-A_\text{lens}\\
&= 2(14.186)-2.868\\
&= 25.504
\end{align*}
$$

Now we have to deal with the two small regions created by the smaller circle. For these, I will be using [the (rather lengthy) formula for the area of an asymmetric lens](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html),

$$
\begin{align*}
A_\text{asy} = & \ r^2\arccos\left( \frac{d^2+r^2-R^2}{2dr} \right)
+ R^2\arccos\left( \frac{d^2+R^2-r^2}{2dR} \right) - \\
& \frac12 \sqrt{(-d+r+R)(d+r-R)(d-r+R)(d+r+R)}, \tag{**}\label{**}
\end{align*}
$$

where $r$ is the radius of the smaller circle, $R$ is the radius of the larger circle, and $d$ is the distance between the centers of the two circles. Here, $r=1.64$, $R = 2.125$, and $d=1.455$. Observe the diagram below.

[image]

The light blue region is the asymmetric lens we will be finding the area of, and we are looking for the area of the two green regions. Using \eqref{**}, we [find the area of one asymmetric lens](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1.64%5E2)arccos((1.455%5E2%2B1.64%5E2-2.125%5E2)%2F(2*1.455*1.64))%2B(2.125%5E2)arccos((1.455%5E2-1.64%5E2%2B2.125%5E2)%2F(2*1.455*2.125))-(.5)sqrt((-1.455%2B1.64%2B2.125)(1.455%2B1.64-2.125)(1.455-1.64%2B2.125)(1.455%2B1.64%2B2.125))) to be $A_\text{asy}\approx5.650$, and thus the area of two asymmetric lenses is $2A_\text{asy}=11.300$.

Notice that the intersection of the two asymmetric lenses in the diagram is the symmetric lens from before. Thus, the area of the light blue and dark blue region is:

$$
\begin{align*}
A_\text{blue} &= 2A_\text{asy}-A_\text{lens}\\
&=11.300-2.868\\
&=8.432
\end{align*}
$$

Now, the area of the green regions is equal to the area of the small circle minus the area of the blue regions. The area of the small circle is:

$$
\begin{align*}
A_o &= \pi r^2 \\
&= \pi(1.64)^2\\
&\approx 8.450
\end{align*}
$$

And so the area of the green regions is:

$$
\begin{align*}
A_\text{green} &= A_o-A_\text{blue}\\
&=8.450-8.432\\
&=0.018
\end{align*}
$$

Finally, the area of the entire shape is the area of the two large circles plus the area of the green regions, which is:

$$
\begin{align*}
A &= A_L + A_\text{green} \\
&= 25.504 + 0.018\\
 &= \boxed{25.522 \text{ mm}^2}
\end{align*}
$$